# Update data from previous record

Tags: postgresql

I have data record  like this and I want update blank record from previous filled record

```
Id   name    page is
1.    Snd        11
2.               11
3.    Kiran.     11
4.    Kiran.     11
5.               11
6.               11.
```

I want update data like this

```
Id   name    page is
1.    Snd        11
2.    Snd        11
3.    Kiran.     11
4.    Kiran.     11
5.    Kiran      11
6.    Kiran      11.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Click: demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=72bb4bb7f023d2992bc7ed27ee953ab1)

```
SELECT
    t1.*,
    (SELECT name FROM mytable WHERE name IS NOT NULL AND id <= t1.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
FROM mytable t1
```

The subquery in the `SELECT` list gives out all not-null `name` values for each id that is prior the current `id`. After that the record with the highest id is ordered to the top. With `LIMIT 1`, this one is the only result. So this is the most recend not-null value.

The `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE mytable t
SET name = s.name
FROM (
    SELECT
        t1.id,
        (SELECT name FROM mytable WHERE name IS NOT NULL AND id <= t1.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
    FROM mytable t1
) s
WHERE t.id = s.id AND t.name IS NULL
```